What to use for text search for a niche e-commerce site using Postgres
I have this small/medium e-commerce site for a niche market. We have tens of thousands of products and are looking to implement of fully functional search bar (previously searched through guided flow/buttons + filters).
The products table in Postgres has many fields that a user might search on (e.g. color, size, material, etc) but the biggest problem is that taxonomy/nomenclature/naming isn’t super standardized for the market so what we have labeled, for example, as a square, a user might search for a polygon or equilateral rectangle instead.
I did some preliminary research into elastic search but I don’t know if it’s worth the overhead and if it’ll solve the taxonomy issue. Do I need to have an internal mapping of words that lead to our version of the taxonomy before building the search query? And at that point should I just use Postgres’s built in index queries?
Did some preliminary research into elasticsearch

Check pgvector, that's on a whole different level of text search: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=em0PKDGzzlQ
